# How Do I get the Name of The inputBlob That Triggered My Azure Function With Python

Tags: python, azure, blob, azure-functions

I have an azure function which is triggered by a file being put into blob storage and I was wondering how (if possible) to get the name of the blob (file) which triggered the function, I have tried doing:

```
fileObject=os.environ['inputBlob']
message = "Python script processed input blob'{0}'".format(fileObject.fileName)
```

and

```
fileObject=os.environ['inputBlob']
message = "Python script processed input blob'{0}'".format(fileObject.name)
```

but neither of these worked, they both resulted in errors. Can I get some help with this or some suggesstions?

Thanks

Comment: Any luck in figuring this out?  If so, would you mind showing us your answer below?

Comment: @DavidActualX I was unable to do this with Python unfortunately

Comment: @Kikanye Is it still the case that this is not possible??!

Comment: @jtlz2 I found a way around it by passing the name of the file through a queue message, but no it is still not possible so far as I know

Answer (score 2):

The blob name can be captured via the Function.json and provided as binding data. See the {filename} token below. 
Function.json is language agnostic and works in all languages.

See documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings for details.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "image",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "path": "sample-images/{filename}",
      "direction": "in",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnection"
    },
    {
      "name": "imageSmall",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "sample-images-sm/{filename}",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnection"
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: my function.json is fine but I want to use the filename in my code with python, so you know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the file name of the file that triggered your function you can to that:

Use {name} in function.json :

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "path": "MyBlobPath/{name}",
      "direction": "in",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnection"
    }
  ]
}
```

The function will be triggered by changes in yout blob storage.

Get the name of the file that triggered the function in python (**init**.py):

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    filemane = {myblob.name}
```

Will give you the name of the file that triggered your function.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any information about what trigger you used in your description. But fortunately， there is a sample project [`yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples`](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples) on GitHub for Azure Function using Python which includes many samples using different triggers like [queue trigger](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/queue-trigger-tagging-images/function/run.py) or [blob trigger](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/blob-trigger-read-write-blob/function/run.py). I think it's very helpful for you now, and you can refer to these samples to write your own one to satisfy your needs。

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using an blob trigger, but the trigger is not the problem, I understand that I just want to know if there is a way to retrieve the actual name of the file and not just 'inputBlob'.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the name of the inputBlob is not currently possible with Python Azure-Functions. There are open issues about it in azure-webjobs-sdk and azure-webjobs-sdk-script GitHub:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1090

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1339

Comment: That's crazy! Still the case?

Comment: @jtlz2 with Azure Functions V2 generally available this might be fixed. Last I've checked Python V2 functions were still in preview but improved a lot many aspects including things not possible in V1 and performance improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I am not sure it is fixed yet though!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly it's still not possible. 
In Python, you can do:

```
import azure.functions as func
import os
def main(blobin: func.InputStream):
    filename=os.path.basename(blobin.name)
```